# "Whether" or "how"?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

Further, it is unclear how tenant farmers, those without titles, and women farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme.

Shouldn't there be "whether" instead of "how"?

Comment: Both are grammatical. They mean different things, at least in intent.

Comment: @Lawrence - It might be appropriate to post an _answer_ that _explains_ the difference (which I, admittedly, would have difficulty articulating).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks. Looks like others have taken up the challenge already. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How" means "in what manner". "Whether" refers to uncertainty as to something being true or not. So as it's currently phrased, the sentence is taking as a given that the farmers etc. are within the ambit, and expressing uncertainty as to in what manner this is so. If "whether" were substituted for "how", then the sentence would be saying that the speaker isn't sure that the farmers etc. are in the ambit.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Further, it is unclear* [***how*** tenant farmers, those without titles,
>   *and women farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme*].
>
> [2] *Further, it is unclear* [***whether*** tenant farmers, those without
>   *titles, and women farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme*].

Both constructions are possible, though they have different meanings.

The bracketed expressions are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions).

[1] is an 'open' interrogative, which questions the reason for (or in what way are) the farmers within the ambit of the scheme. The meaning is:

*“The answer to the question ‘How would tenant farmers, those without titles, and women farmers be within the ambit of the scheme?’ is unclear.”*

[2], by contrast, is a 'closed' interrogative, which questions the possibility of the farmers being within the ambit of the scheme. The meaning is:

*“The answer to the question ‘Will tenant farmers, those without titles, and women farmers be within the ambit of the scheme?’ is unclear.”*